# jquery - Send JSON data via POST (ajax) and retrieve in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

At the moment I'm trying to use ajax to send objects via POST to be processed on the receiving end.

```
var studentString = JSON.stringify(studentArray);

console.log(studentString);

// process the form
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process.php',
        data: {'students': studentString}, 
        dataType: 'json', 
            encode: true
        })
```

The output after JSON.stringify is as follows, so everything would seem to be okay so far.

```
[{"name":"bob","gender":"m","level":"4","topic":"subtraction"},
 {"name":"john","gender":"f","level":"3","topic":"addition"}]
```

On the receiving end (php side) I'm trying to retrieve the data using json_decode, as follows:

```
$result = json_decode($_POST['students'], true);
```

However, after that I am at a loss. How can I loop through the resulting array to output the details on each student, one at a time? Or output (for example), the name of each student?? I've tried variations of

```
foreach ($result as $k => $value) { 
    $msg .= $k . " : " . $result[$k];    
}
```

...but I'm not having any luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does var_dump($result); gives ?

Comment: @Yonel has provided a good solution to your question. You might also want to look at the [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp) php tutorial for simpler examples and explanation or better check out the [php page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). Hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$result` is an `array` of elements, so try this:

```
foreach ($result as $data) { 
    echo $data['name']." : ".$data['gender']; //etc.   
}
```

Comment: I've tried the above suggestion, but no result.

var_dump($result)  gives the following:

[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: @mike I guess you try `json_decode($_POST['students'], true);`, note that the 2nd param `true` say that these objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Comment: Third time's a charm - json_decode($_POST['students'], true); gave me a result. 

Thank you for your help - it's very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process.php',
        data: {'students': studentString}
    })
```

**process.php**

```
foreach ($result as $k => $value) { 
    $msg = "name is:" . $value['name']; 
    $msg .=  ", gender is:" . $value['gender'];
    // add other 

    echo $msg."<br>";
}
```